# Codename one push notifications with php issue

Tags: php, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, codenameone

I've enabled push notifications in my app, added the build hints, registered the api on the play developer console, created and loaded the apple certificates on my server. When I test the app on a device it successfully registers for push notifications. However my issue comes in with trying to actually send a push notification. I want it to send through PHP. I use this code which is taken straight from the developer guide. However this does not work... Is it a problem with my code or did I do something wrong in the enabling push notifications process.

```
<?php

include("config.php");

$args = http_build_query(array( 'certPassword' => 'XXXXXXXX', 'cert' 
=>   
'http://kyven.co.za/mibrand/certificate/XXXX.p12',
'production' => false,
'device' => null, 'packageName' => 'za.co.bonyelo.mibrand', 'email' 
 =>     
'kyri88@gmail.com', 'type' => 1,
'auth' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
'body' => 'Test'));
$opts = array('http' =>
array(
'method' => 'POST',
'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',   
'content'     
=> $args
) );
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$response = file_get_contents("https://codename-    
one.appspot.com/sendPushMessage", false, $context);

die(json_encode($response));
?>
```

Comment: Adding a bounty won't help if the only people who see your post are people who don't know PHP such as me. I added the PHP tag to your post

Comment: Which response you are receiving?

Comment: @Andrew It's empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it. This is the code I used

```
<?php

include("config.php");

$args = http_build_query(array('token' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
'certPassword' => 'XXXXXXXX', 'cert' =>     
'http://XXXXXXX/XXXXX/XXXXX/Certificates.p12',
'production' => false,
'device' => 'cn1-ios-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
 'packageName' => 'za.co.bonyelo.mibrand', 'email' =>    
'kyri88@gmail.com', 'type' => 1,
'auth' => 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
'body' => 'EAT MY BALLS'));
 $opts = array('http' =>
array(
'method' => 'POST',
'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',   
'content' => $args
) );
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$response =   
file_get_contents("https://push.codenameone.com/push/push", false,   
$context);

die(json_encode($response));

 ?>
```